# Windows TCP Socket Timeout C++

Tags: c++, tcp, timeout, winsockets

I have a question

How to know if a client didn't respond to the server during a specified time ?!

I am using threading not select function.

your help will be greatly appreciated :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to look into [setting the socket option][1] as follows:

```
setsockopt(sockid, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,(char *)&tv,sizeof(struct timeval));
```

Having that done, you can check againt `SOCKET_ERROR` when calling the receive and/or send functions. The specific error code can be obtained by calling `WSAGetLastError`.

This is one of those potential error codes:

> WSAEWOULDBLOCK
> 10035
>
> Resource temporarily unavailable.
>
> This error is returned from operations on nonblocking sockets that cannot be completed immediately, for example recv when no data is queued to be read from the socket. It is a nonfatal error, and the operation should be retried later. It is normal for WSAEWOULDBLOCK to be reported as the result from calling connect on a nonblocking SOCK_STREAM socket, since some time must elapse for the connection to be established.

Comment: Thank you so much ?
if i understood you answer it is just for setting timeout value at the socket 
but what happens if a timeout occurs will it calls a function ? .. I want to be notified at the server that a time out has occurred

Comment: @RehabReda: you will be notified by the return value.

Comment: the return value from this function ?
 recv(clientSocket, receivedData, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

what will it be ? 
and really thank you :)

Comment: @RehabReda You're expected to have read the Winsock documentation, which clearly states that recv() return SOCKET_ERROR on error, with a side-effect in the value returned by WSAGetLastError().

Comment: @EJP: strictly speaking, not -1, but SOCKET_ERROR.

Comment: @LazloPapp You don't have any evidence about who downvoted the answer. If you are trying to thank me for the correction, or even acknowledge it, you're going a strange way about it.

Comment: @EJP: I cannot acknowledge what you wrote because it does not seem to be true unfortunately. It is not EAGAIN and EWOULDBLOCK, but WSAEWOULDBLOCK. I acknowledge the WSAEIMTDOUT part, thanks. That was correct an observation.